When is a $\Delta$-skeleton irreducible for diffusion processes?
Say we are given a diffusion process $X$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$, that is positive Harris recurrent. That is, for any measurable set $A$ with $\tau_A=\inf\{t\geq 0:X_t\in A\}$ and some $\sigma$-finite measure $\mu$, then $P(\tau_A<\infty)=1$ whenever $\mu(A)>0$ (Harris recurrence). A positive Harris recurrent process additionally satisfies the condition that the invariant measure is finite.
By theorem 6.1 in Meyn and Tweedie, it claims that is $X$ is positive Harris recurrent, then $X$ is ergodic if and only if there exists a $\Delta$-skeleton chain $(X_{\Delta n}, n\in\mathbb{N})$ that is irreducible. By a similar paper from the same authors, they define an irreducible chain to be a Markov chain $X$ such that $L(x,A)=P_x(\tau_A<\infty)>0$ whenever $A$ has positive measure, for all $x$.
My question is, for the diffusion process $X$, assuming the usual conditions, when can we say that there exists a skeleton for $X$ that is irreducible provided that $X$ is positive Harris recurrent? Or, equivalently, when is positive Harris recurrence identical to ergodicity for diffusion processes? Lastly, does the dimension $n$ of the state space impact this result? I would think that the nice properties of diffusion processes might cause that indeed positive Harris recurrence is identical to ergodicity, yet, so far, I have not found any proof or counter example.
Any help is welcome!
